# Le roi existait avant que son sujet ne se fasse tuer

Tags: subjonctif

> Le roi existait avant que son sujet ne se fasse tuer.

ou

> Le roi existait avant que son sujet ne se soit fait tuer.

Pourquoi le subjonctif présent peut-il être utilisé s'il s'agit du passé?

Answer (score 5):

1. Pourquoi le subjonctif ?

   Au moment où le roi existait, son sujet ne s'était pas encore fait tuer.

   Il s'agissait encore bien alors d'un fait hypothétique et donc rapporté par le subjonctif, toujours utilisé après *avant que*.
2. Pourquoi le présent du subjonctif peut-il être utilisé ?

   Les formes au passé et au présent du subjonctif sont toutes deux courantes et sans différence des sens significative.

   L'imparfait du subjonctif est il me semble aussi possible dans un registre très soutenu :

   > Le roi existait avant que son sujet ne se fît  tuer.